# custom paperclip validation error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, paperclip-validation

I have this validation for content type:

```
validates_attachment_content_type :photo, :content_type => /^image\/(jpg|jpeg|pjpeg|png|x-png|gif)$/, :message => 'file type is not allowed (only jpeg/png/gif images)'
```

I want only the message above to be displayed but instead it says

```
 Photos photo content type file type is not allowed (only jpeg/png/gif images)
```

because its a photos model and attached file photo.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
> Not a real solution but a Easy one is to skip paperclip validation and
> write custom one
>     validate :check_content_type
>     
>       def check_content_type
>        if !['image/jpeg', 'image/gif','image/png'].include?(self.image_content_type)
>         errors.add_to_base("File '#{self.image_file_name}' is not a valid image type") # or errors.add
>        end
>       end
```

Comment: please note that you need to add a condition to validation:

    validate :check_content_type, if: ->(){ image.present? }

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to this party.

```
validates_attachment_size :image, :in => 0.megabytes..2.megabytes,  message: " is too large, try less than 2mb  or for help"
```

Gets you:

Should get you closer to home, with an output of:

"Image file size is too large, try less than 2mb"

Answer (score -3):

Hello please d validation paperclip avtar image

```
attr_accessible :avatar

has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :small => "60x60>", :thumb => "60x60>" }

validates_attachment :avatar, :presence => true, 
:content_type => { :content_type => "image/jpg" }, 
:size => { :in => 0..1000.kilobytes }
```

Comment: what? this doesn't answer the question

Comment: NOthing about :message here, which won't work anyways.